# Linear homogeneous polynomial sequence is a regular sequence.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be a field and consider $K[x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1}]$, the polynomial ring over $K$ in $n+1$ variables. Let $A_i \subset K$ be finite sets with at least $2$ elements, for $i=1,\ldots,r$ and $r\leq n.$ Let $f_i=\prod_{a\in A_i}(x_i-ax_{n+1}).$ Then how can I show that $f_1,\ldots,f_r$ form a regular sequence in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}]$?

I have tried by induction. But could not prove it. Help me.Thanks.

Comment: The height of $I=(f_1,\dots,f_r)$ equals $r$, hence the grade of $I$ is also $r$. Then, since $f_i$ are homogeneous they form a regular sequence.

Comment: How the height of the ideal is $r ?$ and what is grade of an ideal   ?

Comment: ok, but what you have written previously is not clear to me, can you please explain it a little more ?

Comment: @Panja If $P$ is a minimal prime ideal over $I$ then which polynomials are contained in $P$ and therefore generate $P$?

Comment: Thanks for editing it rightly @ user26857. For each $i$ there will  be $a_i \in A_i$ such that $x_i-a_ix_{n+1} \in P,$ am I right sir ?

Comment: @Panja Yes, you are. And moreover, $P$ is generated by such linear polynomials cause they generate a prime ideal. (Btw, try to write @ and user26857 without space between them in order to ping me.)

Comment: ok, so it is clear that height of $I$ is $r,$ but why the depth in $I$ is also $r$ ?

Comment: @Panja Since we are living in a Cohen-Macaulay ring.

Comment: By Cohen-Macaulay ring property the ideal $I$ is unmixed. But then how one argue that $f_1,\ldots,f_r$ will form a regular sequence ?